# Display DIV on right click of image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out how I can get a DIV to show at the position of the mouse when someone right clicks on an image. An example can be found [here](http://www.icstone.us/).

I've searched around and found the following code...

```
$('img').bind('contextmenu', function(e){
return false;
});
```

This of course will prevent the right click. Though I don't know how to make the DIV appear at the location of the mouse click.

May I please get pointed in the right direction?

Thanks! ​

Comment: your link only goes to a file directory.. im not seeing an example.

Comment: Oh my. It appears it got taken down in the past hour.

It's just supposed to show a DIV absolutely positioned where the mouse is when there is a right click on the image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've thrown together a quick demo ([check it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonmerino/qKejd/2/)) of how to possibly do this. The div is absolutely positioned and we capture the `contextmenu` event, on which we `preventDefault()` and set the position of the `div` based on the `pageX` and `pageY` key's in the `event` object.

The JS looks something like this:

```
$('body').on('contextmenu', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('div').css({
        'top': event.pageY,
        'left': event.pageX
    });
});​
```

And the CSS looks something like this:

```
body {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}

div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;    
    background-color: #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}​
```

I've tested the demo in the latest Firefox and Chrome, as well as IE7 - IE9, and it has worked in all of them. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `offsetX` and `offsetY` properties of the event object that gets passed to the `contextmenu` handler like so:

HTML:

```
<img src="http://mikecane.files.wordpress.com/2007/03/kitten.jpg" alt="click me, I'm a kitten!" id="picture" />

<div id="pictureCaption">Pretty picture of a kitten</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Javascript:

```
​$('#pictureCaption').hide();

$('#picture').contextmenu( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#pictureCaption').offset( {top: e.offsetY, left:e.offsetX} ).show();
})​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​;​​​​
```

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/HFC5g/